# Access different arrays with similar keys

Tags: php

I have this array

```
<?php
$themename = "So";
$shortname = "se";

$options = array (
             array( "name" => "the_firstname",
                    "desc" => "The firstname of a person",
                    "id" => $shortname."_the_firstname",
                    "type" => "text",
                    "value" => ""), 

array( "name" => "the_lastname",
       "desc" => "A persons lastname",
       "id" => $shortname."_the_lastname",
       "type" => "text",
       "value" => ""),
     );

foreach($options as $key => $value)
{
   echo $value['id']."<br/>";
}
?>
```

with similar keys for instance the `id` key.I would like to access the `id` value of the first array.

Doing this `echo $value['id'][0]."<br/>";`  or  `echo $options['id'][0]."<br/>";` isn't helping.

How can i show the value of the first `id`?.

Comment: Other way round! You need `echo $options[0]['id']."<br/>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo `$options[0]['id'];` should do the trick on top level, inside the `for` loop this should work: `$value['id']`. You don't need the `[0]` here, since `$value` contains the first (0) element inside the `$options` array.